# Javascript Interpreter related

Tags: javascript

I have a question regarding JavaScript Interpreter or can say compiler .

```
console.log("The future says:", future());

function future() {
return "You'll never have flying cars";
}
```

so as the above example function was declared later before its been called to print. so my question is does this happen for all other identifier or just for functions , and why this function will work . please explain briefly 
Thank you